# How to recharge the wabbajack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I was in Solitude doing a bunch of quests, when I completed one and got the wabbajack. I looked it up online and saw what it could do, but I don't know if I can recharge it. How can I recharge the wabbajack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recharge the Wabbajack as with any other enchanted weapons or staffs.

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Recharging

You need a filled soul gem in your inventory.

Go to the inventory menu, scroll down to the Wabbajack, select "Recharge", and select a filled soul gem.

Comment: thx for the help